# Is it possible to change the margin, header, footer of IE while printing page

Tags: internet-explorer, printing

My clients requirement is that application itself change margin of the page and hide the header and footer while printing the page in IE. It is possible in chrome easily with css but I tried to find the solution over the internet. I tried changing the registry but there is also permission issue and css doesn't work. If there is any way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried CSS media queries for print instead of screen?

Comment: Yes, I did it doesn't work. Even though IE greater than equal to 9 supports css3 it cannot control the page setup.